# How to check a virtual function on an object instance is a certain implementation

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am trying to check if the virtual function on an certain object instance is from a certain implementation. Intuitively it looks like the following code segment:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:

    virtual void method()
    {
            printf("This is from A \n");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void method()
    {
            printf("This is from B \n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.method();
    if (b.&method == &B::method)
    {
            printf("Horray! simple. \n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

But obviously the line `if (b.&method == &B::method)` doesn't work.

Can you kindly suggest how this should work? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain *why* you would want to do this we might be able to help you better? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Related reading [about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If this is object of type B than obviously method overload for B would be cold. So can't understand the question.

Comment: I don't know the answer for this and from an OO point of view, it is actually wrong.  If you use virtual functions, you should just call them and don't worry about the implementation.  When dealing with exceptions to this rule, usually, the type of the object is inspected ([typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), dynamic_cast)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's to debug through a prod system. Yeah I of course can just do inspecting or `dynamic_cast` whatever, but in the other way round I guess C++ doesn't block working it out this way.

Comment: @stefaanv Then I guess you can just wait and see how others answer this question. It's not everyone asking here are learning their programming 101.

Comment: why not use the `typeid` function ?

Comment: It's usually always from the most child class the implementation (except you call the virtual function somewhere in the constructor chain). If you are somehow worried that your declaration does not match with the base class one and you have c++11 access just use the override keyword and the compiler will check for you. Else there is actually no way of testing this (and I don't see other cases where this should be an issue). If you check by typeid or some RTTI function and it is a B object all overloads from B will be called (except in some cases during construction).

Comment: Voted to close as **unclear** question. I can guess at some possible intended questions. But exactly which one this was intended to be, is completely open. As stated it's just meaningless.

Comment: @AlexSuo: I hope you weren't offended by my comment.  I reread the question and my comment and without knowing your background or reason for asking the question, I still think it is a valid comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you kindly suggest how this should work?

In this trivial example, the member function pointer of an instance of `B` obviously has the address of the member function of the class `B` there is no point in testing this.

In general, if we had a pointer or reference to an instance of an unknown derived class, such test couldn't be written in standard C++. There is no way to get the address of the function to which a virtual call resolves at run time.

However, GCC does have an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html) that allows you to do exactly that.

```
 typedef int (*fptr)(A *);
 fptr p = (fptr)(a.*fp);
```

Or, if the compiler documents the ABI that it uses, you may be able to use the specification to extract the address from the member function pointer.